# 'select new' doesn't work in LINQ to DataSet.CopyToDataTable()

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, linq-to-dataset

In the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

"Creating a Custom CopyToDataTable Method" Paragraph  > Example

I tried to do something similar. This is my code:

```
ObjDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(querySQL, conection);

//Create a DataSet object:
ObjDS = new DataSet();

ObjDA.Fill(ObjDS, "Table1");

DataTable MyTable = ObjDS.Tables["Table1"];

//IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
var query =
    from user in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
    where user.Field<string>("Name").StartsWith("c", true, null)
    select new
    {
        Name = user.Field<string>("Name")
    };

DataTable orderTable = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

The issue is in "query.CopyToDataTable": There isn't an implicit reference conversion "AnonymoustType#1" to "System.Data.DataRow".
If I write "select user", it works ok but the problem is: select new.

If I write:

```
query = (...) as IEnumerable<DataRow>
```

query always return null.

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually follow the procedure that is described in the article? As the article explains, `CopyToDataTable` by default only works on an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. If you want to use the method on a custom type you need to [**Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

All of the examples in that section assume you have followed the process and created the custom `CopyToDataTable<T>` method first.

Comment: your link: "The CopyToDataTable methods, however, only operate on an IEnumerable source where the generic parameter T is of type DataRow." Is this not right?:
'IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from user in MyTable.AsEnumerable()
    where user.Field<string>("Name").StartsWith("c", true, null)
    select new
    {
        Name = user.Field<string>("Name")
    };'

Comment: @karmany the reason the code in your first comment doesn't work is because the object you are new-ing up *isn't* a `DataRow`. You can't just take an arbitrary type and say "`as DataRow`" to get one; it has to derive from `DataRow` for that to work. An arbitrary anonymous type won't qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Why `query` in *your* code example should have `CopyToDataTable` function? `query` is an IEnumerable where T happens to be anonymous type with one property (`Name`):

```
select new
                {
                    Name = user.Field<string>("Name")
                };
```

If you really want to enjoy the CopyToDataTable method, you should stick to the original code example:

```
DataTable orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"];

IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate") > new DateTime(2001, 8, 1)
    select order;

DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

You should create a custom CopyToDataTable method in order to support what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx

Comment: `query` is not an anonymous type; it is an `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` happens to be anonymous, but you can still call the `CopyToDataTable` extension method on it. The problem is there isn't a matching overload of that method unless you implement your own.

Comment: Thanks. "select order" works fine but "select new" doesn't work. The original example code (third code) uses "select new". I can't use "select new"?

Comment: @karmany Create your own `class` and your own CopyToDataTable<> extension method. Like: `CopyToDataTable<KarmanyClass>`